# How do I use the list name as part of column name using tidyr?

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I have a nested JSON file that is a pretty simply structure.  The list name is flavor, and then there is a nested `df` one level below.  One of the columns is nested further.  How can I use the name of the list "flavors" as a prefix to the column names when I `unnest`?  I would be looking for column names like `flavor.id`,  `flavor.name`, etc.

I don't have a great reprex example, but I'd be looking to use some form of `tidyr` or `purrr`.  I tried to use `purrr::flatten()` to no avail.

Sample Reprex

```
sample <- list(
  flavor = structure(list(nested_col = list(structure(list(column = 0L,id = "B30D41F4-5684-11E1-8E9A-8F09EE5110CB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                                       structure(list(id = "B30B5B28-5684-11E1-8E9A-8F09EE5110CB", column = 0L), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
                         short_name = c("Bi", "Br"), abbr = c("RR", "CHOC"), long_abbr = c("BXB","BK"), id = c("13", "11"), name = c("Rock n Road","Chocolate")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,2L)))
```

I would be looking to extract the list into a `tbl_df`.  The corresponding columns would look something like `flavor_nested_col`, `flavor_short_name`, etc.

Comment: Added reprex to question.

Comment: The column names in the nested column is `column', 'id', so the corresponding changes names are `flavor.column` and `flavor.id`

Comment: How would I change all the columns to have flavor as part of the prefix?

Comment: At the end, do you want a list of tibbles or just a single tibble

Comment: Just a single tibble.

Comment: Is that doable?  The solution you removed seemed to get me most of the way there.

Comment: It could be doable, but I was not sure about the correct expected output